# Extract number Excel

Tags: excel

I need to use excel to extract numbers from 34"51'53.878 into separate cells as follow

34

51

53.878

I was able to figure out the 34 and 53.878 using below but unable to do the 51 (mid) part.

=LEFT(C1,FIND(""",C1)-1)

=RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-FIND("'",C1))

I think I have to use Mid function but not sure exactly how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MID function takes arguments (Text, Start index, number of characters)

You can figure out the number of characters by taking the end index - the start index - 1(to drop the last quote):

```
=MID(C1,FIND("""",C1)+1, FIND("'",C1)-FIND("""",C1)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

if one has the dyanamic array formula in Office 365 put this in the first cell:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'",""""),"""","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"))
```

And excel will spill the results to the right.

[image]

If not put this in the first cell:

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"'",""""),"""","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),COLUMN(A1))
```

And drag to the right:

[image]